# Регулярное выражение для удаления комментариев в notepad++

Tags: html, css, регулярные-выражения

Очень часто требуется из файла удалить все комментария: в HTML (`<!--Текст-->`) или CSS (`/*Текст*/` и `// Текст`).

Подскажите такие регулярные выражения, чтобы избавится в файле от всех комментариев.

Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

На первый взгляд нужны такие регулярки

```
<!--.*?-->
```

и

```
\/\*.*?\*\/
```

Но возможно, у нотепада++ есть свои особенности. Если там есть галочка "жадный режим", то можно его выключить и убрать знаки вопроса с регулярок.

Также эти регулярки могут плохо обрабатывать текст, если комментарии растянуты на несколько строк. В этом случае ищите галочку "многострочный режим".

Comment: KoVadim, предлагаю заменить `.` на `[\s\S]`: будут учитываться символы переноса строк → многострочные комментарии найдутся без галочек. Результаты: [**HTML**](https://regex101.com/r/mY0sB5/1), [**CSS**](https://regex101.com/r/mY0sB5/2). Полагаю, в данном ответе лучше написать универсальное решение, не зависящее от редактора: про Notepad++ сказать не берусь, но у меня в Sublime Text нет таких галочек. Спасибо.